# How does one recover a multiplexed video stream with missing headers?

Tags: video, codec

I have some video files which were stored with the format headers in separate files.  Unfortunately, the disk crashed, and the header information has been lost.  I still have large chunks of stream data though.  Before I start writing brute-force code to figure out the parameters, are there any tools available for recovering this sort of thing?

update:  Further research and analysis indicates that this is multiple video streams multiplexed into a single file, with codec data hard-coded into the recording software.  As such, repair is likely impossible.  Software capable of scrounging such a file and extracting likely video frames might have some success, but I do not find any such software available. If anyone knows of any I would be happy to test it out and review it.  If this moves the question beyond the scope of this site, feel free to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to extract header from other file (e.g. create a new one with that recording software) and prepend it to your stream.

On Windows you can use that command to concatenate files:

```
copy /b header.hdr + stream.mov outputFile.mov
```

Comment: The problem in this case was that the recording software doesn't store the headers as part of the files. Parameters are hard-coded into the software.

Comment: Is it possible to reinstall that recording software? A few months has passed since the question was asked - have you found a solution?

Comment: Alas, it doesn't seem like there's going to be a solution.  The recording software in question is incapable of reading past the damaged bits in the files, and further study indicates that it may be multiplexing multiple video streams into a single file, which makes attempts to repair it pretty well futile. I'm afraid it's beyond my ability to recover, and I haven't found any software designed to extract video frames from such files.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such tools to my knowledge. You will probably have to make these headers yourself. Usually you don't have all that much parameters to set in a format header. If all the streams have the same origin you will be able to use the same header for all streams.

Just look into the format specification and edit a sample header in a way it could fit your stream data.

Comment: Alas, that is the conclusion I was coming to myself.  Unfortunately, little details like what format the video is in are considered proprietary by the company that wrote the recording software.  Hence why I was looking for something capable of doing its own analysis.